# Rails not indexing locations

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

So I tried to add this code to first the views and then the controller. It didn't work and gave me an error : undefined method save for 4:Fixnum.

Code:

```
<% unless location.user.interests.blank? %>
  <% @merged_array = location.user.interests.split(',').uniq + 
                       current_user.interests.split(',').uniq %>
  <% location.score = @merged_array.length - @merged_array.uniq.length %>
  <% location.score.save %>
<% else %>
  <% location.score = 0 %>
  <% location.score.save %>
<% end %>
```

But then I removed it from both controller and views..... Now the index page isn't showing the locations at all I checked and the show page is working and records still exist

Comment: Please add code in your question instead of providing external links.

Answer (score 1):

This is really **not** the way it should work.

- Just read a bit about the MVC pattern - it's worth it!
- You shouldn't check in production credentials into your repository - especially not if it is public.
- Checkout https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv to keep your keys and passwords privately.
- You should change your passwords immediately!
- The error you got is because `location.score` is an integer not an object - `location.save!` will save the object with its new score.

PS: You don't want to be the guy who let production creds into the guide for new employees. https://www.reddit.com/r/cscareerquestions/comments/6ez8ag/accidentally_destroyed_production_database_on/

Beside of that, Keep going!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry forgot that it only displays locations within a 50 mile radius and i was travelling...... Silly me :)